# Getting the number of non-zero elements in rows and columns of a dgTMatrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, apply

I have a sparse `dgTMatrix`:

```
require(Matrix)
mat <- as(Matrix(c(rep(0,15000),rnorm(6000)),nrow=30,ncol=700,sparse=T), "dgTMatrix")
```

In reality it's much much bigger (35000 x 750000).

I'd like to compute for each row and each column the number of non-zero elements.

Is there anything faster than:

```
apply(mat,1,nnzero)
apply(mat,2,nnzero)
```

For that?

Comment: `rowSums(mat != 0)` and `colSums(mat != 0)`?

Comment: Yep, that works great.